# Numpy 'where' returns empty array for all 0s array for condition >= 0

Tags: python, numpy

I am using np.where function to get indices where the value matches 0. But the following code returns me empty array, which is not expected.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,0,0])
np.where(a[a>=0])
```

This gives: `(array([], dtype=int64),)`.

Could anyone please point out what I am missing?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. `a>=0` gives you all `True`, i.e `a[a>=0]` gives you `a`, which does not contain any non-zero element. So `np.where(a)` returns empty array.

Are you looking for `np.where(a>=0)`?

Answer (score 1):

you are telling to find index where a[ a>=0]
a>=0 returns a [True,True,True,True] then a[a>=0] returns [0,0,0,0] then there's no True condition to return.

Maybe you want to do

```
 np.where(a>=0)
```

Comment: my response is the same as Quang Hoang I think he explains it better:
np.where returns the arguments where the list have a non-zero element so you were using the original list (for your example a[a>=0] it's a )